# How to implement table partitioning in Android (SQLite)?

Tags: android, sqlite, database-partitioning

As I know, SQLite does not support table partitioning. However, when an application deals with big data, I think table partitioning is a good consideration. Unfortunately I can't find an example implementation to do this in Android until now. The condition would be as follows.

- The table will grow over time
- Old rows are rarely queried/updated; typical operation will be, but not limited to, searching or exporting/backing up to a file
- Old rows are frequently queried for such a summary (e.g. by using aggregate function)

I am curious what approach is used by messaging apps or accounting apps to deal with it. So, how to do this in Android?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I don't know the exact size it will be. Suppose that there are maximum of 200 entries in a day with an average 50 bytes per entry. In a year it will be `50 B × 200 × 365 = 3,650,000 B ≈ 3.48 MiB` and in 10 years it can reach `34.81 MiB`. I don't know whether it can be called as big data in Android. Someone said that cursor size could not exceed 1 MB.

Comment: What do you mean with _"big data"_? Please be specific.

Comment: Table with so so many many rows. Did I use a wrong term?

Comment: Quantify _"so many"_: 10k, 1M, 1T rows? How big each row? What kind of operations should be performed on each row? Bigdata is mostly a buzzword.

Comment: You are welcome. SQLite can totally handle a DB with that size. You don't need partitioning or anything similar (besides, I'm curious about where you got the idea...)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I got that idea from reading about database optimization. There's an app in my phone (closed source, so I don't know how the database designed/implemented) that going slower over time. So there is no need to do partition although I'll have a `ListView` that display all of the data? (I am thinking about updating the question :D)