# Advantage of creating separate databases for each table in SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design

I saw a couple `android` applications (popular applications like *Facebook* and *Google Play Store*) with separate `databases` for each `table` created in design and i wonder why has it been done. What is the advantage of creating a new database for every table in `SQLite` ? Any ideas ?

Comment: can you provide links to these? for certain complex situations it may makes sense, but not really on a phone that I can think of immediately.

Comment: It's a simplification of the table partitioning concept (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364796/how-to-implement-table-partitioning-in-android-sqlite))

Comment: @Jim one of my co-workers has `SQLite Editor` application installed. Inspecting the database schemas; it seems both *Facebook* and *Google Play Store* applications are using such approach. I don't have a link or any shot of schemas tho

Comment: @Tobor I've checked the question. So is it about *big data* at all ?

Comment: I guess so. If your data aren't that big, I'd go for a single db (easier to maintain). There could be other reasons for tables being separated, like different users could see different data (only their ones and not the data from other users) or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question's comments, FB and Google Play are mentioned. If you are building enterprise level code that may have patterns, objects or recycled code, then maybe using multiple databases is easier than re-engineering complex systems like that.

One other reason, similar, is that you may be merging two dissimilar systems into a single app and the database schemas have conflicting table names, stored procedures, etc. So, complexity alone would not determine it, but porting existing systems without redesigning or engineering them might result in this.

Last, having multiple teams develop different aspects of a complex app might - but most likely the DB engineers would hash out their differences rather than build multiple databases.